# JS - Почему не воспроизводится анимация

Tags: javascript, canvas

По каким-то непонятным причинам `Canvas` не хочет выполнять анимацию заполнения холста через `setTimeout()`. В браузере получается просто конечный результат, а промежуточного движения к нему не наблюдается.

```js
function GenerateMap() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  if (elem && elem.getContext) {
    var context = elem.getContext('2d');
    var size = 32;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 900, 600);
    var iRandDirection, iSeedPos = [],
      iNumSeeds = document.generator.numSeeds.value,
      iNumUpdates = document.generator.numUpdates.value;

    for (var i = 0; i < iNumSeeds; i++) {
      iSeedPos[i] = [Math.floor(Math.random() * (900 + 1)), Math.floor(Math.random() * (600 + 1))]
      context.fillRect(iSeedPos[i][0], iSeedPos[i][1], size, size);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < iNumUpdates; i++) {
      setTimeout(generation(), 10);

      function generation() {
        for (var j = 0; j < iNumSeeds; j++) {
          if (iSeedPos[j][0] == 0 || iSeedPos[j][0] == 899 || iSeedPos[j][1] == 0 || iSeedPos[j][1] == 599) {
            iSeedPos[j] = [Math.floor(Math.random() * (900 + 1)), Math.floor(Math.random() * (600 + 1))]
            context.fillRect(iSeedPos[j][0], iSeedPos[j][1], size, size);
            continue;
          }
          iRandDirection = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 + 1));
          if (iRandDirection == 0) {
            context.fillRect(iSeedPos[j][0], iSeedPos[j][1] + 1, size, size);
            iSeedPos[j] = [iSeedPos[j][0], iSeedPos[j][1] + 1];
          } else if (iRandDirection == 1) {
            context.fillRect(iSeedPos[j][0] + 1, iSeedPos[j][1], size, size);
            iSeedPos[j] = [iSeedPos[j][0] + 1, iSeedPos[j][1]];
          } else if (iRandDirection == 2) {
            context.fillRect(iSeedPos[j][0], iSeedPos[j][1] - 1, size, size);
            iSeedPos[j] = [iSeedPos[j][0], iSeedPos[j][1] - 1];
          } else if (iRandDirection == 3) {
            context.fillRect(iSeedPos[j][0] - 1, iSeedPos[j][1], size, size);
            iSeedPos[j] = [iSeedPos[j][0] - 1, iSeedPos[j][1]];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="600">
 </canvas>
<form name="generator">
  <label for="numSeeds">Число зёрен</label>
  <input name="numSeeds" type="text">
  <label for="numUpdates">Число итераций</label>
  <input name="numUpdates" type="text">
  <input type="button" onClick="GenerateMap()" value="Сгенерировать">
</form>
```

Comment: Добавь весь код html и css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут ошибка:

```
setTimeout(generation(), 10);
```

А должно быть:

```
setTimeout(generation, 10);
```

В `setTimeout` передается только имя функции без скобок. `generation()` означает что функция выполняется сразу.

Comment: В setTimeout передается только название функции. Без скобок. А я ставил скобки, из-за этого и не работало.